# ComboBoxEdit DevExpress

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

Buen día,

Tengo un comboBoxEdit de DevExpress, este tiene tres opciones quemadas, Yes, No y vacío (por defecto). Requiero que si un usuario digita un valor diferente a la lista quemada y haga click en una parte vacía del formulario (no otro control, sino en una parte vacía) el ComboBox se limpie.

Yo implemente un LostFocus que funciona bien cuando selecciono otro control pero no sé dispara cuando selecciono una parte vacía del formulario. Eso está hecho en c#

¿Alguien sabe como puedo obtener el comportamiento deseado?

Comment: En vez de usar LostFocus prueba Leave [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.leave?view=windowsdesktop-6.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.leave?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione. Gracias @rexxarcat por tu tiempo. Comparto la solución [https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.ComboBoxEdit]

Básicamente es obligatorio utilizar DataMember y ValueMember y obviamente todo lo que eso conlleva!

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta. Por cierto, lee [answer].